# TFS 2015 Archive Files task: Error spawnSync ENOENT

Tags: visual-studio, azure, tfs

[image: Description of the error]

I'm trying to build a windows service and archive files in the process in TFS Online. Archive files task fails at this ambiguous error. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: How's your build definition like? How did you configure Archive Files task? Try to create a new build definition and add only task Archive Files with default setting to see whether you'll reproduce this issue.

Comment: Also, do you use hosted build agent or on-premise agent? Share your build definition and entire log.

Comment: Add a variable of "system.debug" with a value of "true" to your build and run it again...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today.

Fixed it by

1. Right click solution + properties
2. Configuration Properties -> Configuration.
3. If there are any unchecked build buttons.

Check them all like in the image below.

[image: image with checked checkboxes]